# Problem with .env file setting for docker-compose.yml file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

I try to set variables in my `docker-compose.yml` file in a separate `PORTAL_ENVIRONMENT.env` file 
I don't know, what I am doing wrong.
I have this output:

```
WARNING: The POSTGRES_DB variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The POSTGRES_USER variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The POSTGRES_PASSWORD variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The HOST variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The PORT2 variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The PORT3 variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The PORT1 variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
```

`docker-compose.yml` looks like this:

```
  client_app:
    env_file:
      - PORTAL_ENVIRONMENT.env
    image: 'client:latest'
    build:
      context: ./
    container_name: client
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/${POSTGRES_DB}
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      - SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO=update
      - HOST_NAME=${HOST}
      - CREDIT_POST=${PORT1}
      - PRODUCT_POST=${PORT3}
    ports:
      - ${PORT2}:8080
```

(there are 3 separate modules,every looks almost the same)

`PORTAL_ENVIRONMENT.env` looks like this:

```
HOST=localhost

PORT1=8089
PORT2=8090
PORT3=8091

POSTGRES_DB=create_credit
POSTGRES_USER=user
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pass123
```

I run it with:

```
sudo docker-compose up --force-recreate --build
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When specifying your service's environment, you want those environment variables (HOST, POSTGRES_DB, etc) to be accessible to docker-compose at the time that it parses your docker-compose file. To do that, you should put them in a file called just `.env`. (Alternatively, if they are set in your shell environment at the time you run docker-compose, that is okay too, but you probably want to be keeping them in a .env file.)

Instead, you're trying to use `env_file:` in the docker-compose file. That specifies that the service that uses the `env_file` should look in that file and then update its own environment with that information. `env_file` is like `environment:`, but it looks at a file. It's just for the container to use, and docker-compose can't use it to set up how to run the container.

If you'd like to also pass variables from a `.env` file into a container, you can do something like one of these:

```
environment:
 - MY_VARIABLE=${VARIABLE_IN_MY_ENV_FILE}
 - MY_VARIABLE_SAFER=${VARIABLE_IN_MY_ENV_FILE:?err}
```

(the `?err` will cause the startup to fail if the environment variable is not set, which is a nice trick.)

If you want the `.env` file used by docker-compose to not be named `.env` (maybe you are fond of the name you already have for some reason), docker-compose also has its own `--env-file` command-line option which you can use to specify the path of the `.env` file to use.

If you're still curious or confused you could also check out the docker-compose [Environment Variables documentation page](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/) - that one talks about both environment-setting for docker-compose and for containers, all in the same webpage.

Comment: That has solved my problem, thanks for the full explanation! :)

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure you are running docker-compose up in the correct folder where your YML File is, and that you have your .env file in the correct path in relation to your YML file